# Laravel use together in relations like with YII

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in Yii framework we can enforce to use `JOIN` for relations such as this action:

```
public function relations() {

    return array(

        'posts'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'user_id', 'together'=>false),

    );

}
```

how to use this method in laravel?

Comment: Unfortunately Eloquent (Laravel) does not sue JOINs as far as I am aware. However, all you need to know about specifying relationships can be found in the documentation. It's pretty well documented: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: What you are trying to do, it's not clear.